# Generating and inserting large amount of data into MS SQL from WCF

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, datatable

I have a task to generate and insert about 1'000'000 rows into 2 tables. The difficulty is that I have to insert existing foreign keys, so I get data from other tables first...
And than I try to generate new DataTable with 1000000 rows to paste it with SqlBulk... But this generations takes too long (~4000 rows per minute!) Here's the code, maybe someone can help optimize it...

```
public void GenerateData(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, int Size)
    {
        DataTable theDatetime = new DataTable();
        theDatetime.Columns.Add("Datetime", new DateTime().GetType());
        theDatetime.Columns.Add("Date", new DateTime().GetType());
        theDatetime.Columns.Add("Hour", new Int32().GetType());
        DataTable theOverspeed = new DataTable();
        theOverspeed.Columns.Add("CarNumber", new Int32().ToString().GetType());
        theOverspeed.Columns.Add("Datetime", new DateTime().GetType());
        theOverspeed.Columns.Add("DistrictCode", new Int32().GetType());
        theOverspeed.Columns.Add("MarkCode", new Int32().GetType());
        theOverspeed.Columns.Add("OwnerCode", new Int32().GetType());
        theOverspeed.Columns.Add("RecognitorNumber", new Int32().GetType());
        theOverspeed.Columns.Add("Region", new Int32().GetType());
        theOverspeed.Columns.Add("RouteCode", new Int32().GetType());
        theOverspeed.Columns.Add("Overspeed", new Int32().GetType());
        theOverspeed.Columns.Add("Speed", new Int32().GetType());
        Dictionary<DateTime, DateTime> Dates = new Dictionary<DateTime, DateTime>();
        Random TheGenerator = new Random();
        DataTable theCars = getCars();
        DataTable theRecognitors = getRecognitors();
        int[] sizes = new int[5];
        for(int step = 0; step < 5; ++step)
        {
            DateTime Current1 = GetFifthDate(fromDate, toDate)[step];
            DateTime Current2 = GetFifthDate(fromDate, toDate)[step+1];
            int CurrentCount = GetFifthCount(Size)[step];
            for (int i = 0; i < CurrentCount; ++i)
            {
                var aDate = GetRandomDate(Current1, Current2);
                if (!Dates.ContainsKey(aDate))
                {
                    InsertFact(theCars, aDate, theRecognitors,
                        theDatetime, theOverspeed);
                    Dates.Add(aDate, aDate);
                }
                else
                {
                    i--;
                }
            }

        }
```

And the InsertFact method

```
private void InsertFact(DataTable theCars,
        DateTime theDate,
        DataTable theRecognitor, DataTable theDatetime, DataTable theOverspeed)
    {
        Random theGenerator = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        DataRow rowDate = theDatetime.NewRow();
        rowDate["DateTime"] = theDate;
        rowDate["Date"] = theDate.Date;
        rowDate["Hour"] = theDate.Hour;
        theDatetime.Rows.Add(rowDate);
        int car = theGenerator.Next(theCars.Rows.Count);
        int recognitor = theGenerator.Next(theRecognitor.Rows.Count);
        DataRow rowOverspeed = theOverspeed.NewRow();
        rowOverspeed["CarNumber"] = theCars.Rows[car][4];
        rowOverspeed["Datetime"] = theDate;
        rowOverspeed["DistrictCode"] = theRecognitor.Rows[recognitor][3];
        rowOverspeed["MarkCode"] = theCars.Rows[car][3];
        rowOverspeed["OwnerCode"] = theCars.Rows[car][2];
        rowOverspeed["RecognitorNumber"] = theRecognitor.Rows[recognitor][2];
        rowOverspeed["Region"] = theCars.Rows[car][1];
        rowOverspeed["RouteCode"] = theRecognitor.Rows[recognitor][1];
        rowOverspeed["Overspeed"] = theGenerator.Next(10, 40);
        rowOverspeed["Speed"] = theGenerator.Next(100) > 40 ? 70 : 90;
        theOverspeed.Rows.Add(rowOverspeed);}
```

GetRecognitors

```
private DataTable getRecognitors()
    {
        DataTable Result = new DataTable("Recognitors");
        using (SqlConnection theConnection = new SqlConnection(str))
        {
            theConnection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter theAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Recognitor", theConnection);
            theCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            theCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
            theAdapter.SelectCommand = theCommand;
            theAdapter.Fill(Result);
        }
        return Result;
    }
```

GetCars

```
private DataTable getCars()
    {
        DataTable Result = new DataTable("Cars");
        using (SqlConnection theConnection = new SqlConnection(str))
        {
            theConnection.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter theAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from Car", theConnection);
            theCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            theCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
            theAdapter.SelectCommand = theCommand;
            theAdapter.Fill(Result);
        }            
        return Result;
    }
```

Comment: `new DateTime().GetType()` => `typeof(DateTime)`, `new Int32().GetType()` => `typeof(int)`, `new Int32().ToString().GetType()` => `typeof(string)` -> man, you've made my day. Also, show `getCars` and `getRecognitors` code, please.

Comment: Sorry for my poor c# skills, it's my first project...

Comment: Any reason why you don't do this in SQL? Generally much faster. Also do you need random dates? Can't you increment the datetime with 1 second instead of random -> check if already used etc...

Comment: I have to do this generation from WCF, it's part of task... If there is a way to generate sqlScript which will fill the database with random values... I would be glad to use it...

Comment: @LeYar I recommend taking a look at this site: http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/db2luw/how-to-easily-populate-a-table-with-random-data-7888. It explains everything you need to know to generate insert statements with random data in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me, your code has too much idle passes, and their number increases during data generation. Look at these two lines:

```
for (int i = 0; i < CurrentCount; ++i)
{
    var aDate = GetRandomDate(Current1, Current2);
    if (!Dates.ContainsKey(aDate))
    {
        // insert
    }
    else
    {
        i--;
    }
}
```

The more data you've generated, the more times the condition `Dates.ContainsKey` evaluates to true. Because of normal distribution of generated numbers, the time, required to generated the unique number increases in nonlinear manner.

You definitely should to revise the approach, used for date generation.

P.S. `Dictionary<DateTime, DateTime> Dates` => `HashSet<DateTime>`.